# Best way to pass an image as props?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-props

I am trying to pass an image as props from a parent component to a child component like this:

Parent:

```
const StarterContent = {
    image: require('../../assets/images/bike.png'),
    title: 'Starter',
    price: '$149/mo',
    description:
        'Get to know Onfleet. Track, dispatch, manage, and analyze your fleet.',
    buttonText: 'Start Free Trial',
};

...

<PricingCard content={StarterContent} />
```

Child component:

```
<Image src={content.image} alt={content.title} />
```

But the image doesn't render, any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your property value can be a `require` statement?

Comment: Add the code instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Child component:

```
<Image src={content.image.default} alt={content.title} />
```